# Downloading google sheets using python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

For some reason one of our unix servers is still using python 2.6. I cant upgrade it’s version to v3 due to restrictions. Frustrating I know.

Anyway, I am wondering if there are still working libraries for v2.6 that would enable me to download google sheets. I’ve been trying to search but no luck.

Comment: Anaconda/miniconda can install python to user directory without root. Why do you need to use python 2.6.

Comment: Ouch, Python 2.6 dates back to 2008. Would upgrading to the most recent 2.7.18 version help?

Comment: @jarmod I’ve been requesting to upgrade its version to latest actually but they’re afraid it would break or impact the current scripts running in 2.6. Lol

Comment: I guess if you can't find a Sheets library compatible with Python 2.6 then this might be the argument you need to embark on a potential upgrade. I don't know of such a library (but I haven't ever looked for it either). But the upgrade to 2.7.18 might be beneficial.